# Lodash in angular 4, this is undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, lodash

I am using lodash in angular 4 and am using times to create an array of numbers. I don't understand why but I cannot use 'this' inside of the lodash function as it comes up as undefined, instead I have to assign this as self first.

```
private arrayNum: number[] = [];

ngOnInit() {
 let self = this;
 _.times(31, function (n) {
   self.arrayNum.push(n + 1);
 });
}
```

Can anyone please explain why this is or if I am making a mistake with lodash. Thanks

Comment: Use fat arrow syntax...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `arrow function` for callbacks to keep the context.

```
_.times(31, (n) => {
  this.arrayNum.push(n + 1);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an arrow function to keep the same context.

```js
 _.times(31,  (n) => {
   this.arrayNum.push(n + 1);
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately @Pengyy answered just a bit quicker than you and as they are identical I will give it to him